# Export Node as Static HTML in a Zip

Tags: 8, nodes, importing-exporting

I have a content type called "Lesson". Lessons have fields like Title, Body, Image, Video, and Topic (term ref).

I would like authors to be able to export any lesson they have created into a Zip that would contain:

- a static html version of their node
- all of the media they have uploaded for the node

I have looked at several export modules, but they seem to mostly export as csv or be designed for re-importing into a drupal site.

They also do not handle media attached to the entity very well.

Any suggestions on where to begin?

Comment: If you can do a PDF instead of a zip archive, you can use [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print). Entity Print can also do Word and some other formats, so you might be able to hack/extend the module to do Zip export as well, but it probably won't be easy.

Comment: Many thanks @PatrickKenny, this will be a good hold over until I have a better solution.

Comment: Maybe also have a look at the [Tome](https://www.drupal.org/project/tome) module which can export an entire site as static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with Tome Drupal Module. Which provides the functionality of exporting site content as Static HTML. By default it doesnt provide option to download as zip. You might need to tinker around to find a way to create zip.

For single page export you can check the discussion in this link.

https://www.drupal.org/project/tome/issues/3184258

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Tome to see if there is any way to export a single node at a time (i.e. when the author requests to export).